# nmake Makefile cl.exe include folder

Tags: header, include, makefile, cl.exe

I have a project written in and I'm trying to compile it using `nmake` Makefile. The project setup is as follow:

```
MyProject\
    Makefile
    src\
        includes\
            header1.h
            header2.h
        module1\
            module1.h
            module1.c
        module2\
            module2.h
            module2.c
        some.h
        some.c
```

1. `module1.c` includes `header1.h` and `header2.h`.
2. `module2.c` includes `header2.h`

Now in my `Makefile` I'm trying to compile module1 first and then module2.

```
CC = cl.exe
CFLAGS = /link /DLL
build:
    $(CC) src\module1\module1.c $(CFLAGS)
    $(CC) src\module2\module2.c $(CFLAGS)
```

Now I'm getting error of `Cannot open include file: includes\header1.h`. After some research in this website, everyone suggested to use `/I DIR` flag. So in my `Makefile` I added:

```
CFLAGS = /link /DLL /I src\includes
```

But I'm still getting the same error. Can someone please help me on how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I am having the same problem. Wasting hours on it.